# 22.7GB for storing "org.mozilla.pluginContainer" even after deleting Mozilla Firefox

Tags: macos, storage, firefox

I deleted Mozilla Firefox and I checked my file storage and saw that within my caches folder I have a folder called **org.mozilla.pluginContainer** which contains a **fsDataCache** folder which is taking 22.7GB of space.

Can I simply empty that folder as I am not sure whether that folder will have any effect on other apps within my laptop. Is it safe to remove that folder completely?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely delete the contents of the fsCachedData folder.

If you're still worried, don't delete the data immediately but copy it to a different folder. You can then delete it after a few days if you haven't experienced any problems.

Comment: No problem :-) Please mark as answered if it solved the problem for you!